# Opening a link and a div at the same time

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

Few days ago I tried to create a system that jQuery will enable me to display a link and a div when you click, everything about

Link to project: http://jsfiddle.net/HCAfz/

A main condition is that when you click on a link opened up and changed the status of only one div, and not all on the page.

I'm such a div in each category with 40 and the creation of separate classes in the css div again, misses the point.

What can my project completed in jquery? any suggestions

Comment: I have no idea what this question is actually asking for.

Comment: The project when you click opens a new div with the id = "new". If the project I have such links 1000 is how to make just one change to the status of id = "new" and not all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, using `next`:

http://jsfiddle.net/HCAfz/2/

```
$('a.yourLink').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).next('.hiddenDiv').show();
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the content of a div in particular call it by an ID. Just set the property id='something' and call it with JQuery: $('#something').html('Add this HTML to div')

It's very alike when you work with CSS. Just e specify a ID or class and set your style rule by it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more generic procedure.

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/otherLink" 
   id="yourId" 
   class="opens-a-link-and-shows-a-div">Click here</a>
<div id="div-to-show-when-yourId-clicked" style="display: none">
    Your link has opened in a new window
</div>
```

and javascript

```
$('a.opens-a-link-and-shows-a-div').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      var div_name = '#div-to-show-when-%-clicked'
          .split('%').join($(this).attr('id'));
      $(div_name).show();
      window.open(this.href, '_blank');
 });
```

(See my [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/pGNVK/))

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, an expanded version of your HTML would look like this:

```
    <a href="http://www.yoursite.com/otherLink" target="blank_"  id="yourId">Click here</a>
    <div class="hiddenDiv">Your link has opened in a new window</div>
    <div class="hiddenDiv">Your 2nd link has opened in a new window</div>
    <div class="hiddenDiv">Your 3rd link has opened in a new window</div>
    <div class="hiddenDiv">Your 4th link has opened in a new window</div>
```

You could use this jQuery to open only the div after the link and not the others with the same class:

```
    $('a#yourId').click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          $(this).next('.hiddenDiv').show();
     });
```